# The correct form of "the same way"/"the same way as"

Tags: grammar

In an example sentence, what would be the correct form of using "the same way":

> Sell your fruit the same way Walgreens does.

or

> Sell your fruit the same way as Walgreens.

I'm leaning towards the first one but only by ear, I don't have a grammatical explanation for it.

Comment: Either is fine.

Comment: The _as_ is a version of _that_ (which is also OK) used with _the same way_ to introduce a relative clause. Since it's a _way_ (i.e, a manner adverb), it can't be the subject, so it's deletable. Hence, all three are grammatical and mean the same thing (i.e, all are equally correct, none is more correct than any other): _the same way Walgreen's does, the same way **that** Walgreen's does, the same way **as** Walgreen's does_.

Comment: @JohnLawler So you're saying that "Sell your fruit the same way as Walgreens." is in fact incorrect because it misses a verb? I'm not debating whether "as" is redundant but that if it's used, "does" has to be used as well.

Comment: No, that isn't what I'm saying. I didn't mention deleting the pro-verb _does_ and I didn't delete it because I wasn't discussing it. If you do delete it, of course, you can still use _as_, and you can still use Zero, but you can't use _that_.

Comment: @JohnLawler, you say: *If you do delete it, you can still use **Zero***. Do you mean the following is correct: *sell your fruit the same way Walgreens*.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the first, because "the same way" is adverbial, and needs to point to a verb.  "Walgreens" is not a "way".   That said, most people would not object to your second rendering; as Jan Borchardt pointed out, they will catch the implied but unspoken/unwritten verb (does).

Comment: Is this one of those things that became "correct" because of how frequently it's used?

Comment: I suppose so. Although I am not a descriptivist; that is, I don't think simple repetition necessarily makes something correct. You can Google and see how often a phrasing (or a spelling) is used, but I would also recommend consulting a dictionary; it's entirely possible for the majority of web users to get something wrong. Including answerers on this site.

Answer (score 0):

The second is correct.  There is a lot of the phrase left out, but is understood.  Sell your fruit the same way THAT Walgreens does. (SELLS THEIR FRUIT) The words in caps are the words that are understood, but not spoken.

Based on my experience learning English grammar, Latin grammar, French, Spanish and German, too.